# How to fix unreliable Realtek Wireless card on Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: ubuntu, kernel, drivers, wifi

I have a Realtek RTL8188CE wireless card and it works fine when I have a strong signal, but if I get even slightly away from the wifi I lose connectivity even though there is a strong Rx signal.  I suspect that the Tx power from my laptop is not strong enough, but running:

`sudo iwconfig wlan0 txpower 23`

was ineffective.  The card would not let me set it above 20 dBm.  How can I either fix the flakiness or increase the Tx power?

Answer (score 5):

A lot of Googling around, reading forums, and trial and error revealed that the problem is the driver.  There is a newer driver with the flakiness bug fixed, but it doesn't compile on kernel >=3.8 because of a changed header file.  Also the 20 dBm limit is hard coded into the driver even though the wireless card is capable of more.

I fixed the compile bugs and the 20 dBm limit (adjusted up to 33 dBm, use with caution and check local laws), and placed the driver on GitHub.  It is very easy to install, and fixes the flakiness and the 20 dBm tx power limit (this is why I love open source :-) ).  [The Git Hub page](https://github.com/FreedomBen/rtl8188ce-linux-driver) can be found here:  https://github.com/FreedomBen/rtl8188ce-linux-driver

To install, run this from a terminal:

`git clone https://github.com/FreedomBen/rtl8188ce-linux-driver`

then follow the instructions in `README.md`

EDIT:

This driver also covers the 8192ce/de/se and the 8723e

Comment: This saved me endless amounts of frustration.  Thank you! <3